# Watir running error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- watir (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from Bot.rb:1:in `'

Anyone know how to fix this??

Comment: Where is the problem? Update your question with program.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a Gem manager? They are highly encouraged. I recommend `rbenv`, but `rvm` works as well. Check out our installation guides on our website: http://watir.com/guides/